# Adding new option in sharepoint 2010 site actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am working on sharepoint server 2010. I want to add an option to

> Site
>   Librart Tools ribbon
>   Documents
>   Share & Track

By default a link called "E-mail a Link".

How can i add custom link by using feature enabling programatically.....?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy a feature with a CustomAction element.
There is a full example on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407221.aspx